# function_score failed to parse search source. expected field name but got start_object

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a problem with elasticsearch.
I just add the function_score part, before it works well

What is the problem with this request :

```
    {

    "index":"appartoo",
    "body":{
        "from":"0",
        "size":"30",
        "sort":[
        ],
        "_source":{
            "exclude":"user"
        },
        "query":{
            "bool":{ ... }, #This part works well
            "function_score":{
                "query":{
                    "bool":{
                        "must_not":[
                            {
                                "term":{
                                    "images.0.contentUrl":"images\/profile.png"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term":{
                                    "images.0.contentUrl":"images\/no-image.png"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "boost":"5",
                "boost_mode":"multiply"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error is :

> parse_exception: failed to parse search source. expected field name
>   but got [START_OBJECT]

I use ES 2.4

Comment: `function_score` needs to go inside the `bool` query as well.

Comment: @Val how ? I've now the error query_parsing_exception: [bool] query does not support [function_score]

Comment: It needs to be inside your `filter` or `must` or `should`. Show the query part

Comment: Good, there you go !